# Debian laptop loses all network access, can't ping anything

Tags: linux, networking, wireless-networking, router, debian

I've got a laptop running Debian (Jessie) that for whatever reason has decided it hates wireless. It has some kind of Intel wireless card (not sure which), and so uses the iwlwifi package for wireless, and up until recently it worked great. Now, however, the laptop intermittently loses full network access and is currently on a 1-month streak of no network access and no internet access (I don't use it very often for the same reason that I am posting here). I've been trying to solve it for the past 2-3 months (!!!) with little to show for my efforts. Here's what I do have:

1. I can't ping anything. Not the router, not any other computer on the network, nothing outside, absolutely nothing. Other computers on the network cannot ping it either.
2. The laptop IS receiving an IP address from the router (DHCP is working, somehow), but even if I set it as a static IP it doesn't work. Completely changing the IP doesn't help either.
3. `ifconfig` doesn't show anything abnormal, nor does doing `dmesg | grep wlan0`. Screenshot of the `ifconfig` below. If needed I can provide the exact output of the dmesg (I'm not as good at reading that).
4. There's no bridging set up whatsoever (screenshot of doing `brctl show` below), yet Wireshark records huge amounts of STP packets, which I understand to be heavily involved in switching, bridging, etc., all of which is not happening on my network. My network is a simple home network with a router connected to a modem. [Here's a link to the capture file from Wireshark.](https://www.dropbox.com/s/tbzc4yzy6ely1ex/Internet%20Glitch.pcapng?dl=0)
5. I checked the MAC address of router and confirmed that the laptop has it right by doing `arp -a`.
6. Connecting the laptop directly to the router with an ethernet cable works fine.
7. I have two routers of the exact same model (Asus RT-N56U) at two different locations. One is on a far more complicated setup (I don't remember the exact details, but it's behind another router), yet it yields the same result. However, when I try and connect the laptop to another model of router, it works fine. This initially made me think that it's an issue with the router, but since the issue started randomly and I've updated both routers (and the laptop, for that matter) several times, I doubt it. Unfortunately, buying a new router/s is not an option.
8. Doing 'ifconfig wlan0 down' and then 'ifconfig wlan0 up' (which I'm told should restart the wireless card/firmware) doesn't help.

Here's a screenshot of the `ifconfig`. I would've copied and pasted it, but this was posted from a different computer.

[image]

So, the end question is, how can I fix it?

EDIT: Results from two commands I was asked to post:

```
sourec@yottawasp:~$ sudo lshw -C network
  *-network               
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: 82579LM Gigabit Network Connection
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 19
       bus info: pci@0000:00:19.0
       logical name: eth0
       version: 04
       serial: e0:db:55:b5:fe:06
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd   100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=e1000e driverversion=2.3.2-k firmware=0.15-4 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
       resources: irq:45 memory:f7c00000-f7c1ffff memory:f7c39000-f7c39fff ioport:f080(size=32)
  *-network
       description: Wireless interface
       product: Centrino Advanced-N 6235
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: wlan0
       version: 24
       serial: b4:b6:76:e7:ad:a1
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=3.16.0-4-amd64 firmware=18.168.6.1 ip=192.168.1.133 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11abgn
       resources: irq:44 memory:f7b00000-f7b01fff

sourec@yottawasp:~$ sudo lspci -vnn | grep -i net -A 12
00:19.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Intel Corporation 82579LM Gigabit Network Connection [8086:1502] (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Dell Device [1028:05dc]
    Flags: fast devsel, IRQ 45
    Memory at f7c00000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [disabled] [size=128K]
    Memory at f7c39000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [disabled] [size=4K]
    I/O ports at f080 [disabled] [size=32]
    Capabilities: [c8] Power Management version 2
    Capabilities: [d0] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
    Capabilities: [e0] PCI Advanced Features
    Kernel driver in use: e1000e

00:1a.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #2 [8086:1e2d] (rev 04) (prog-if 20 [EHCI])
    Subsystem: Dell Device [1028:05dc]
--
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Centrino Advanced-N 6235 [8086:088e] (rev 24)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Centrino Advanced-N 6235 AGN [8086:4460]
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 44
    Memory at f7b00000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=8K]
    Capabilities: [c8] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [d0] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
    Capabilities: [e0] Express Endpoint, MSI 00
    Capabilities: [100] Advanced Error Reporting
    Capabilities: [140] Device Serial Number b4-b6-76-ff-ff-e7-ad-a1
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi

07:00.0 SD Host controller [0805]: O2 Micro, Inc. OZ600FJ0/OZ900FJ0/OZ600FJS SD/MMC Card Reader Controller [1217:8221] (rev 05) (prog-if 01)
    Subsystem: Dell Device [1028:05dc]
```

Comment: Please post full output of *sudo lshw -C network* and *lspci -vnn | grep -i net -A 12*.

Comment: Added output in the original question. I had to to 'sudo  lspci -vnn | grep -i net -A 12' because it wasn't showing full capabilities and instead just showed "Access denied" for capabilities.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I disabled 802.11n. On my model of wireless card, iwlwifi seems to have some issue with 802.11n. This explains why it had an issue with two identical routers but not with a cheap ISP-provided router - perhaps the two routers support 802.11n but the old ISP-provided router doesn't.